# SSSD server as centralized authentication

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd

I have a linux server that successfully communicates with Windows Active Directory to get user logins, using SSSD. Everything works good.
Now, I'd like to allow a second linux server to use those AD logins by communicating only to the SSSD server. So without joining the second linux server to the AD domain.
Is it possible, and what's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: have you found out?? please post the answer once you found out..